# Is correct set the ID_USR in every table (to register the creator)

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm actually stuck with a question. I'm actually modeling my database, and i thought that is a good ideia keep the user that created the row linked to the row in table. Here's an example of a table that i created:

```
CREATE TABLE HOMEOPATIA(
    ID_HOM BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    DAT_CRI_HOM DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    VER_HOM INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
    ID_USR_CRI BIGINT(20) NOT NULL,
    NOM_HOM VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_HOMEOPATIA PRIMARY KEY HOMEOPATIA(ID_HOM),
    CONSTRAINT FK_HOMEOPATIA_USUARIO FOREIGN KEY (ID_USR_CRI) REFERENCES USUARIO(ID_USR)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

But when i did reverse engineering i didn't like the result because there are many tables linked to the user. Anyone can help me with that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if you want to keep track of the user who created the record, you need to have the User ID as a FK in the table. There is no other way around it.